# Get coordinates from photo with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, exif

I was following this thread [Get coordinates from photo with JavaScript](http://danielhindrikes.se/web/get-coordinates-from-photo-with-javascript/) to obtain the latitud and longitud from a picture (I checked the picture and has the properties), I'm trying to get with javascript using:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("#file-input").on("change", function(e) {
            EXIF.getData(e.target.files[0], function() {
             
                var result = EXIF.pretty(this);
                $("#span").text(result);
            });
        });

  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/exif-js/exif-js/master/exif.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<span id="span">Here</span>
```

But it's always returnig as `GPSLatitude` and `LGPSLongitud`: `[3 values]` but I can't access to those properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, make sure the image is fully loaded before trying to read the EXIF header. The EXIF-JS docs warn about it [in greater detail](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js/blob/master/README.md#usage), with specific warnings about jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try EXIF.getTag(this,'GPSLatitude'),
You will get 3 pairs which are separated by commas(,).You can convert that to string and split them in to an array, proceed through remaining steps.

Comment: For anyone that doesnt know gps that well (like me), there are 3 formats and [this lib](https://github.com/perfectline/geopoint) can help converting between the 3